# How to display an image using Sails server?

Tags: sails.js

This could be trivial but I can not find a way to show an image using sails server.

The images, pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg and pic3.jpg are saved under

assets/images/

I write a layout file containing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/styles/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/styles/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body >
  <%- body %>
  <!--SCRIPTS-->
  <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/ang.js"></script>
  <!--SCRIPTS END-->

</body>
</html>
```

and abc.ejs file as

```
<img src="/assets/images/pic1" alt="First slide">
<img src="pic2.jpg" alt="First slide">
<img src="pic1" alt="First slide">
<img src="/assets/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
<img src="/.tmp/public/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
<img src=".tmp/public/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
<img src="../.tmp/public/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
<img src="../assets/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
```

and changed routes.js to contain

```
'/': {
  view: 'abc'
}
```

Nothing showed up except 8 empty image icons.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assets` is the root directory for your public data. So try:

```
<img src="/images/pic1.jpg" alt="First slide">
```

Hope this helps.